# can't access jquery.com website from browser but can ping it and lookup in dns

Tags: web, telnet, ping

I can't access `http://jquery.com/` from any of my browsers. When I try to ping it it works fine:

```
Pinging query.com [70.32.120.107]:
Response from 70.32.120.107: number bytes=32 time=217ms TTL=45
Response from 70.32.120.107: number bytes=32 time=237ms TTL=45
Response from 70.32.120.107: number bytes=32 time=198ms TTL=45
Response from 70.32.120.107: number bytes=32 time=198ms TTL=45
```

I can also find it in DNS:

```
nslookup jquery.com

google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Response:
jquery.com
Address:  70.32.120.107
```

But I can't telnet it:

```
telnet 70.32.120.107 80
Connecting to 70.30.120.107... failed to instantiate connection to 70.32.120.107 80 on port 80
```

The browsers don't seem to have any proxy configured. And the problem seems to be with only jquery.com website, others seem to open OK.

What might be the problem?

Comment: what makes you think that this may be a DNS problem?

Comment: I have no idea where the problem might be. I just listed all the information I have now.

Comment: well, the hostname resolves, both from your local resolver which may still have cached records, as well as from the authoritative nameservers of that zone - so i think one can safely say that DNS is not the problem. You made me think that you believe the problem be caused by DNS because of the DNS tag in your question.

Comment: I see. I remove the tag to prevent confusion. Where do you think should I look for solution? If telnet doesn't doesn't work what can be the problem?

Comment: you may want to add information in which way a request to that host fails, apart from the telnet attempt (which has a funny error message btw, "...connection to 70.32.120.107 80 on port 80", with 80 mentioned twice

Comment: The message is funny because I printed it and made a mistake :) How can I obtain information about `in which way a request to that host fails` ? Is `Error: TimedOut (0x274c). ` helpful?

Answer (score 0):

telnetting to the ip address of a webserver is not a reliable way to test webserver response, because webservers often treat requests by name differently from requests by ip address. In case of larger sites those requests are frequently routed to a different internal webserver by the gatekeeping server, and requests to ip address alone may be ignored entirely.

("by name" means, still the service at the same ip address is consulted, but the request name is passed along with the query, in form of a GET statement followed by an URL, which telnet doesn't do when invoking it with only the ip address - it is not a magic mechanism which somehow replaces ip addresses to locate the receiving server)

You want for that reason to send a request with the name of the server which gives you problems.

Use a webbrowser, which also carries the request name to the webserver, not just the ip address. or look at output of curl when called with the hostname. That should give you an server response which actually relates to the hostname you have problems with.